# Does a quarry keep chunks loaded after it has finished?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

After a quarry has finished its dig (reached bedrock or lava), will the chunks be unloaded or will they remain loaded until the quarry block is removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a quarry will keep chunks within its area of operation loaded before and after doing its thing. They will only be unloaded when the Quarry block is removed.

To test this, I simply set up a system that pumps items out of an Ender Chest (from the Ender Storage mod) into a regular chest near a quarry that had reached bedrock.

[image]

Then, I went to the Nether, restarted the server for good measure, and put items into the corresponding Ender Pouch. They started disappearing, which means that the chunks in the overworld were still loaded.

Comment: did you move the quarry far enough away from spawn? spawn always remains loaded, you can verify loaded chunks with the chickenchunks mod with the command "/chunkloaders"

Comment: @ratchetfreak About 100m from spawn, and reversing the setup (quarry in the nether) produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a quarry will always keep chunks loaded where ever you are in the overworld. The quarry will also stay loaded if you are not on minecraft only if you are on a server that is constantly running.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of buildcraft are you using?

In my version, that's in thekkit 3.1.2 (that's based on minecraft 1.2.5) a quarry does not keep any chunks loaded. You have to place world anchors to keep it working even if you're away (or offline).

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it is auto-loading chunks, and puts a message in chat to that effect

Comment: Not in the version I'm using (I'm not even sure which version it is, as I'm using it inside tekkit).

Comment: The version of BuildCraft that's in Tekkit is pretty much ancient at this point (9 months out of date). I think quarry chunk loading was introduced around BC 3.2.x.

Comment: @lunboks We're not using Tekkit, we're using FTB with the DireWolf modpack. Forestry FTW.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, without a version specified this is a valid answer.